# Map integer or string to a data type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have an application where a specific `message` type needs to be selected based on user input (a `string` or `int`). There is a 1:1 mapping of a (`string` or `int` to a fixed type). For example `1`-> int or `"Apple"`-> `struct Apple` ..and so on.

I tried to map `int` to a type using a template `GetType<>`.

```
struct messageA {int x;};
struct messageB {double y;};


/// Trying to map int to a type
template<int>
struct GetType{};

template<>
struct GetType<1> {
    using type = messageA;
};

template<>
struct GetType<2> {
    using type = messageB;
};
///


/// this some_task function is called from some UI
void some_task(int ID) {

    // here I can not use the ID value in GetType<  >
    typename GetType<1>::type *msg = new typename GetType<1>::type(); 
    
    some_other_generic_function(msg);

}
```

But it seems I can not use this, inside the function `some_task` because `ID` is a runtime argument.
The `switch case` is an option but then every time when a new message type is needed, I need to change the switch case.

What other ways can we achieve the association from `int` to `type`? Can we create some sort of list of types and which can be indexed with `int` (actually I needed `string`, but I will deal with strings later)?

Comment: Does based on user type mean that the user specifies the type, or do you need to deduct it?

Comment: Why not use and `std::map`?

Comment: @Bart `std::map` maps values not types

Comment: `std::variant<messageA, messageB>` seems to be what are after. Should play well with a visitor that invokes `some_other_generic_function`.

Comment: In that case use a factory pattern, depending on the user input you select something with the same code you should have some common basis. Otherwise it will be separate functions anyway.

Comment: @JanGabriel, I updated the question a bit. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: *"The switch case is an option but then every time when a new message type is needed, I need to change the switch case."* - and if what you tried was possible, you'd still need to add a specislization. So it's not like things are really automagical here.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I have a custom reflection library in place. Where user only has to call a MACRO(their type, member1,member2, etc...) and `their type` gets into the type system of my framework.

Comment: My own experience with macro based reflection libraries is that it's never really "simply" something easy for the user. You are already at the first roadblock.

Comment: *What other ways can we achieve the association from int to type* -- Wrap the `int` in a class and provide the proper accessors to the class so that it acts like an `int`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, the actual implementation is templates only, just user-facing, API is macro. I just wanted to index the user-provided types with some key (string or int)

Comment: The macros expanding into templates does not contradict my point. Just so happens the libraries I mentioned also resolved to template metaprogramming attempts.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a type, based on some precondition, is where [Creational Design Patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/creational-patterns) are great. For this specific application I would propose a Factory method. This does mean you require a `messageBase` type class.

Using a base class, it becomes easy to map your type to a specific implementation using a `std::map`. However, you will need to expose shared properties through the base class.

```cpp
struct messageBase {
  virtual std::string print() = 0;
};

struct messageA : public messageBase {
  int x{123};
  std::string print() override { return std::to_string(x); }
};

struct messageB : public messageBase {
  double y{123.321};
  std::string print() override { return std::to_string(y); }
};
```

I find that the mapping part is better to do with a `std::map` than a `switch` due to the ease of extention.

```cpp
// Lookup for ints + str
std::map<int, std::function<messageBase*()>> int_lookup;
std::map<std::string, std::function<messageBase*()>> str_lookup;

// Using a map instead of a switch - Put this in a factory
int_lookup[1] = []() { return new messageA(); };
int_lookup[2] = []() { return new messageB(); };
str_lookup["foo"] = []() { return new messageA(); };
str_lookup["bar"] = []() { return new messageB(); };
```

Example usage and a [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/v5b1fGf7z):

```cpp
// Use the maps to create the "messages" on the fly
std::cout << int_lookup[1]()->print() << std::endl;
std::cout << int_lookup[2]()->print() << std::endl;
std::cout << str_lookup["foo"]()->print() << std::endl;
std::cout << str_lookup["bar"]()->print() << std::endl;

// Output:
// 123
// 123.321000
// 123
// 123.321000
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but unfortunately, I can not change the legacy messages and make them derived from the base class.

Comment: In that case you can still use this approach. However, you will need to implement the structural design pattern called the [decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator). You use this to add functionality to existing classes which are closed for extention. See the updated [example](https://godbolt.org/z/s3oM7GbK8) using a decorator.

Comment: Great, I will try your approach